# Python: Call Dash app with get parameters

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I want to create a dash app that has access to parameters passed in address.  For example, http://localhost:5050?config=bob.json

```
@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('funnel-graph', 'figure'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('Manager', 'value')])
def update_graph(Manager):
   config = ... # get config value of 'bob.json'
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the full address line using [dcc.location](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/location) extracting any parameter values needed.